# Optimize Python Code of 1 Million For Loops

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

Would you have any tips to optimize this code ? It takes about 3 hours to run. Thank you so much!

```
V = np.random.rand(10, 10)

R = np.random.rand(10, 1)

data2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Mean Return", "Standard Deviation"])

for i in range(1000000):

    w = 1 / np.random.rand(10, 1)

    w2 = w/w.sum()

    data2 = data2.append(pd.DataFrame({"Standard Deviation": float(np.dot(np.dot(w2.T, V), w2)),
                                     "Mean Return": float(np.dot(w2.T, R))}, index = [i]))
```

Comment: This isn't a [MCVE], and you haven't explained why you feel it requires optimization. If this is in a function, using `@numba.njit` on the function might help (it's intended to optimize stuff like this, where lots of simple Python operations are mixed with `numpy` code).

Comment: Sorry @ShadowRanger, I've edited my question. This is not part of a function.

Comment: I'd recommend making it into a function (just wrap it in `def main():`, then add `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` at the end of the file to invoke it); running code in global scope harms performance more than you might think (every assignment to, and read from, a global variable involves a `dict` operation; in a function, it's a simple C array indexing operation). And once it's in a function, you can try decorating the function with `@numba.njit` and seeing if that's enough to solve your problem.

Comment: @Shaddow, have you verified that `numba` works with `pandas`?

Comment: `pandas.append` has this note: **Iteratively appending rows to a DataFrame can be more computationally intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original DataFrame all at once.**

Comment: @hpaulj: I have not. It was something to try, and `njit` will at least let you know if it works or not immediately (it forces compilation; if there are unrecognized types, it will died with a `TypingError` so you don't think it's JIT-ing when it can't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken a list comprehension does the same in a couple of seconds:

```
V = np.random.rand(10, 10)
R = np.random.rand(10, 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [float(np.dot(np.dot(w2.T, V), w2)), float(np.dot(w2.T, R))]
        for w in (1. / np.random.rand(10, 1) for _ in range(1000000))
        for w2 in [w / w.sum()]
    ],
    columns=['Mean Return', 'Standard Deviation']
)
```

Comment: thanks but can I ask, why is `for _ in range(1000000)` after `for w in (1. / np.random.rand(10, 1)` ? Why cannot it be before ?

Comment: @ya23 I'm not sure I understand your question correctly: `(1. / np.random.rand(10, 1) for _ in range(1000000))` is a generator that produces the `w` values. You can't do direct assignments in list comprehensions (`w = ...`) so you have to find a way around it (hence also the strange `w2 in [w / w.sum()]`).